# Php configure Unable to build the PostgreSQL extension

Tags: php, postgresql, psql, configure

I'm trying to intall/configure php-8.2.2 on rhel8.7.
This is my configure string:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/www/php-8.2.2 --with-apxs2=/usr/www/httpd/bin/apxs --with-expat --with-openssl=/usr/www/openssl --with-zlib-dir=/usr/www/zlib --with-curl=/usr/www/curl --enable-soap --enable-sockets --with-pgsql=/usr/postgres --enable-sysvmsg --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --enable-mbstring --without-pear --with-external-pcre
```

During installation I receive this error:

```
checking whether to enable pcntl support... no
checking whether to enable PDO support... yes
checking for PDO_DBLIB support via FreeTDS... no
checking for Firebird support for PDO... no
checking for MySQL support for PDO... no
checking for the location of libz... /usr/www/zlib
checking Oracle OCI support for PDO... no
checking for ODBC v3 support for PDO... no
checking for PostgreSQL support for PDO... no
checking for sqlite 3 support for PDO... yes
checking for PDO includes... /home/lmwusr/terna/php-8.1.15/ext
checking for sqlite3 >= 3.7.7... yes
checking for sqlite3_close_v2 in -lsqlite3... yes
checking for sqlite3_column_table_name in -lsqlite3... yes
checking for PostgreSQL support... yes
checking for pg_config... /usr/postgres/bin/pg_config
checking for PQlibVersion in -lpq... no
configure: error: Unable to build the PostgreSQL extension: at least libpq 9.1 is required
```

Postgres 13 is installed and it works. If I run the same configuration with php 7.2, it works fine, same problem also php-8.1.15 and php-8.0.0

This is my environment:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/www/libxml2/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/www/openssl/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/www/curl/lib/pkgconfig::/usr/www/onig/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/postgres/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/www/pcre2/lib/pkgconfig
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/postgres/lib
```

What I can to do/try, for compile php-8.2.2?

Thanks a lot